# Doctrine 2.9.x-dev

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Did somebody tried Doctrine 2.9.x-dev? I am using with symfony 5.2.6. I know it is a dev version  but when run any command I get an error for example:

[critical] Error thrown while running command "'doctrine:schema:create'". Message: "An option named "em" already exists."

and when I run only bin/console i get error

[critical] An error occurred while using the console. Message: "An option named "em" already exists."

An option named "em" already exists.

It is because this is dev version (2.8.4 is working) or am I missing something?

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you use any non-released version? There's no guarantee that this will work

Answer (score 2):

The error comes from `doctrine/doctrine-bundle` - it seems like it is not compatible with `doctrine/orm 2.9.x-dev` yet.

The problem is already being worked on, but the PR has not been merged yet, see: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/pull/1327

If you really need the dev version to work with Symfony right now, you will need to apply the changes manually, but I would recommend waiting for a stable release.